# Mysql join two tables based in id

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is country another one state.Based on country id i need to group the state.I tried with joining but i couldn't get.How to get same table names in one columns and id also.

country example:

[image]

State example:

[image]

Expected Results

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use join. Union with alias will work.
Here's your query:

```
SELECT r.name, r.type, r.parent_id, r.og 
FROM (
    SELECT c.name AS name, 'country' AS type, 0 AS parent_id, c.origin AS og 
    FROM country c
    UNION
    SELECT s.name AS name, 'state' AS type, s.country_id AS parent_id, s.country_id  AS og 
    FROM STATE s  
) as r 
ORDER BY r.og, r.parent_id
```

Here, og is an extra projection created to match your sorting need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from country
join state
on state.country_id = country.origin
```

you can group by by just adding

```
group by country_id
```

As far as mixing the results from two queries, just use UNION ALL between the two queries. Easy.

```
SELECT query 1.
UNION ALL
SELECT query 2.
```